# How do you pick a path to show that the limit doesn't exist for a multivariable function?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

For example I have the question:
Let $D = R^2 /\{(0, 0)\}$ and $f : D → R$ be given by

$f\left(x,y\right)\:=\:\frac{xy\left(x^2\:-\:y^2\right)}{x^4+y^4}$

Show that $\lim _{\left(x,y\right)\to \left(0,0\right)}f\left(x,y\right)$ doesn't exist.
So all I have to do is pick 2 paths and how that their limits disagree.

So my question is what path should I take? Is there a general rule to tell which path to take? How can I tell? My answer considered the limit along the path $x = 2y$. I don't know how it got this

Answer (score 0):

The simpler paths are those of the form $y=mx$. If $m=0$, then you are taking the limit along the line $y=0$, which is $0$. And now there is no point in taking $m=\pm1$ because, since you have that factor $x^2-y^2$, the limit will also be $0$ then. So, taking $m=2$ is a good idea. In this case, you get a limit which is not $0$, and therefore $f$ has no limit at $(0,0)$. Of course, it may well happen that you always get $0$ going along all of these paths and that the limit actually does not exist. You will have to take other paths then (such as, say, $y=x^2$).

Comment: It's worth commenting that because the numerator and the denominator are both homogeneous of degree $4$, the function will be constant along lines $y=mx$ (away from the origin).